# Где хранятся данные пакета пришедшего по сети?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, ос, пакет, сетевое-программирование

Что происходит с пакетом, который пришёл на машину. В частности мне интересно, где хранятся пришедшие данные. я знаю что есть некий буфер с данными, но где этот буфер? Это буфер сетевой карты или это буфер в ядре ос?

Comment: Укажите ОС в метках.

Comment: Сначала в буфере сетевой карты, но не долго. Когда вторая часть прерывания обработана данные уже в буферах ОС

Comment: *я знаю что есть некий буфер* Их несколько. Буфер сетевой карты (аппаратный), буфер драйвера сетевой карты, буфер IP-стека, ... всё в соответствии с OSI, и пакет передаётся с уровня на уровень, в буферы обработчика соотв. уровня с соотв. преобразованиями.